# Filtering a django QuerySet by a previously ordered queryset

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-filter

I am trying to order a queryset by distance from an input location. I am able to order the original queryset that contains the point fields, however when I use that queryset to filter a query on another model then it returns the queryset unordered.  The code is as follows:

Models:

```
class EnglandSpine(models.Model):
    urn = models.CharField(db_column='URN', primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    schname = models.CharField(db_column='SCHNAME', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    postcode = models.ForeignKey(Postcodes3, to_field='pc', on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_column='POSTCODE', max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
class Postcodes3(models.Model):
    gid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    pc = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    latitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    longitude = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
    the_geom = gis_models.PointField(blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pc
    objects = GeoManager()
    class Meta:
        managed = True
        db_table = 'postcodes3'
```

I am able to retrieve an ordered list of postcodes with the following view

views.py

```
class PCSearch(TemplateView, SingleTableView):
    template_name = 'schoolData/pcs.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = PostSearch()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form':form})

    def post(self, request):
        form = PostSearch(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pcps = form.cleaned_data['Postcode']
            pc = pcps.replace(' ','')
            d = form.cleaned_data['Distance']
            ss = form.cleaned_data['schtype']
            gs = form.cleaned_data['gentype']
            adms = form.cleaned_data['seltype']
            pcr = Postcodes3.objects.get(pc=pc)
            area = (pcr.the_geom, Distance(mi=d))
            pcs = Postcodes3.objects.filter(the_geom__distance_lte=area).values('pc')
            pcss = pcs.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance("the_geom", pcr.the_geom)).order_by("distance")
```

Finally I would pass the pcss variable through one more filter to get all the schools...

```
results = EnglandSpine.objects.filter(postcode__in=pcss)
```

But this does not return the query set in any order?

My second approach was to set the `postcode` field in `EnglandSpine` as a foreign key to `Postcodes3` pc and perform Geometry Distance search, but it cant find the related object `postcodes.the_geom`.

Really stuck here and after countless hours I cannot find a specific example that relates to my issue.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: I think your best option is to troubleshoot the foreign key solution. It seems much more elegant.

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the foreign key? You must declare it (as you did) and also assign it before you can use it.

Comment: When I try to use the foreign key with the code - results = results.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance('the_geom', results.values('postcode.the_geom'))).order_by('distance') - it says that 'postc0de.the_geom is not a field.

Comment: Just a tip, you can use back ticks to format code in comments, so it is better to read. Such as `results = results.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance('the_geom', results.values('postcode.the_geom'))).order_by('distance')`.

Comment: It seems like you are fumbling somewhere. My guess would be that `values()` doesn't accept the `'postcode.the_geom'` argument and instead you should just give it `'postcode'`, and then when you use it, use it as `postcode.the_geom`.

Comment: thanks @jpnadas. appreciated. I realised that `results = results.annotate(distance=GeometryDistance('postcode.the_geom', results.pcr.the_geom).order_by('distance)` should be the correct syntax but again it doesn't find the foreign key link.

Comment: When you create your objects, are you setting that field appropriately? Can you log into the database and see how is the data there?

Comment: Thanks @jpnadas. Turns out I was being an inexperienced fool. When trying to reach a foreign key in quotes it turns out you use__ rather than a . Lesson learned.

Comment: Awesome Tom! Consider creating an answer to your own question here, so that people who look for it in the future have a solution!